# Maximum amount of entries in the histogram_bounds

Tags: sql, postgresql

The default limit is presently 100 entries for `histogram_bounds` and `max_common_values` fields in `pg_stats` view. Raising the limit might allow to be made more accurate estimates scanned rows for postgresql planner. Globally, this setting is set by default_statistics_target or can be set on a column-by-column basis using the `ALTER TABLE SET STATISTICS` command.

What is the maximum value of this setting can be set?

UPD:
I found how to look this settings:

Select name, max_val from pg_settings where name='default_statistics_target'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the docs (as of 9.3):

> SET STATISTICS
>
> This form sets the per-column statistics-gathering
>   target for subsequent ANALYZE operations. The target can be set in the
>   range 0 to 10000; alternatively, set it to -1 to revert to using the
>   system default statistics target (default_statistics_target). For more
>   information on the use of statistics by the PostgreSQL query planner,
>   refer to Section 14.2.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html